# Large database for photos

Tags: database, photo

I am creating an app where there will be a lot of photos (like a lot) which would be constantly updated. I was thinking that I should use a 3rd party cloud server. Does anyone have any recommendations on how I can approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Amazon S3 storage, they also have good API's for almost any programming language. See http://aws.amazon.com/s3/